# How do I assign the returned value of a function to a variable?

Tags: c#

***Perhaps this could be more clear.  The method is returning values...but after the value is returned I have no access to it in the rest of the program.  I put a comment on the difficult part.***

```
class CharacterStats
{
    public int CharacterHitPoints()
    {
        int Health = 0;            
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Health = rnd.Next(30,70);
        return (Health);
    }

    public int CharacterStrength()
    {
        int Strength = 0;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Strength = rnd.Next(1,20);
        return (Strength);
    }
}

class ApplicationObject
{
    static void Main()
    {
      string CharName;
      string KeepStats;

      MonsterAttackRolls GoblinAttack = new MonsterAttackRolls();
      MonsterAttackRolls OrcAttack = new MonsterAttackRolls();
      MonsterAttackRolls OgreAttack = new MonsterAttackRolls();
      MonsterAttackRolls DragonAttack = new MonsterAttackRolls();

      MonsterHitPoints GoblinHealth = new MonsterHitPoints();
      MonsterHitPoints OrcHealth = new MonsterHitPoints();
      MonsterHitPoints OgreHealth = new MonsterHitPoints();
      MonsterHitPoints DragonHealth = new MonsterHitPoints();

      CharacterStats PlayerHealth = new CharacterStats();
      CharacterStats PlayerStrength = new CharacterStats();

      Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Realm, the top adventure game in the world!  Please enter the name of your character if you wish to continue:");
      CharName = Console.ReadLine();

      Console.WriteLine("Welcome {0} to Realm!  You will be given stats.  They may be good or they may be bad.\nYou only get 2 rolls for your stats though, so pick wisely!  From there you must fight 4 fearsome beasts.\n  If you survive, you will win the game.  If you die, well, you die.  Press any key to continue.", CharName);
      Console.ReadLine();

      Console.WriteLine("You will be given a strength number which augments your damage. Your strength can range from 1 - 20.\n A strength of 15 or over gives you a bonus to damage.  A strength of 5 or less gives you a penalty.   You will be start with a hit point number between 30-70.  Good luck!");
      Console.ReadLine();

      Console.WriteLine("Your first set of stats is:\n Health = {0}.\nYour strength is {1}.\nIf you would like to roll again press 1.  If you want to keep your stats press any other key.", PlayerHealth.CharacterHitPoints(), PlayerStrength.CharacterStrength());
      KeepStats =  Console.ReadLine();

      if (KeepStats == "1")
      {
          Console.WriteLine("So you want a second set of stats.  Okay.\n Your health is now: {0}.\n Your strength is now: {1}.", PlayerHealth.CharacterHitPoints(), PlayerStrength.CharacterStrength());
          Console.ReadLine();
      }



        Console.WriteLine("Okay {0} you are ready to go.  Good luck!\n.  Once again, your stats are:  Health: {1}\n Strength: {2}", CharName, //How do I access the return value? x 2?;
        Console.ReadLine();
    }







    }
}
```

***Where the comments are in the line just above this is where I want to put the returned values and have access for them the rest of the program.***

Comment: `var myVariable=Console.Readline();` ?? Please follow any C# tutorial on the web

Comment: I am not reading web tutorials.  I was stuck on Chapter 5 of methods from my textbook.  And my search Steve found examples in C, Python, but not in C#.

Comment: In any event I am going to re-read my chapter on Methods.  It is pretty complicated imo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CharacterStats charObj = new CharacterStats();
int CharacterStrengthInt = charObj.CharacterStrength();
int CharacterHitPointsInt = charObj.CharacterHitPoints();
```

EDIT:, since your edited question makes it more clear. I believe you are looking for following.

You need to assign the return values to some variable in your code and then **display the values of those variables in Console.WriteLine**. Otherwise they will be lost.

Something like following.

```
int CharacterStrengthInt = PlayerStrength.CharacterStrength();
int CharacterHitPointsInt = PlayerHealth.CharacterHitPoints();
 if (KeepStats == "1")
      {
        Console.WriteLine("So you want a second set of stats.  Okay.\n Your health is now: {0}.\n Your strength is now: {1}."
       , CharacterHitPointsInt, CharacterStrengthInt);
          Console.ReadLine();
      }
```

Comment: This did not work.  This called the function again.  It did not assign the previous method's return value to a variable in Main().

Comment: @MatthewOttewell, I am not sure how you are trying that. But in your own code you are assigning a value from a method to a variable. See the line `Health = rnd.Next(30,70);`

Comment: I edited my post to show the complete code of the program (except for two other classes that have little to do with this issue).

Comment: That works a lot better.  It doesn't work perfectly but I see that the return value, when first returned, is stored as a variable.  

Admittedly when I call the function again it does not update the values.  That doesn't make sense...

Comment: But that is a very good start.  I had to declare the variables before rather than after.  I thought the returned value was attached some memory that I could access.  Guess not.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply call

```
int strength = characterStatsObject.CharacterStrength()
```

after you created a CharacterStats-Object.

Comment: Okay, so do I need to create the object in the function, or in my main code?

Answer (score 3):

```
CharacterStats objCS = new CharacterStats();
int CHP = objCS.CharacterHitPoints();
int CRS = objCS.CharacterStrength();
```

If you do this in the MAIN clause, you can use both variables